# Not able to connect to SQL in Google Cloud

Tags: sql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am not able to connect to Cloud SQL in GCP,
My spring boot application is hosted in Google Kubernetes,
I am able to connect my application to database from my local
but when I deploy my application image in kubernetes it doesnt work
I checked the logs and got this

```
{
insertId:  "s=5ae000c9c858402ba514b2f9a2a7d34d;i=557f;    b=fef2848a05ed422b811cda756eea59d6;m=2a5164d50;t=58dde1640752b;  x=4a97c620c9fbf136-0@aa"  
logName:  "projects/finomatic  /logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err"  
receiveTimestamp:  "2019-07-17T10:38:04.977705316Z"  
resource: {…}  
severity:  "INFO"  
textPayload:  "2019-07-17T10:37:59.135897Z 1340 [Note] Aborted  connection 1340 to db: 'finomatic' user: 'root' host: '  cloudsqlproxy~129.41.84.82' (Got an error reading communication packets)"  
timestamp:  "2019-07-17T10:37:59.136950Z"  
}
```

so I added my cluster IP in sql Connection tab, but still getting this error
my API works fine when I just preview my app docker image
after deployment api doest work 
getting this error after deploymenet 
`Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection`

Answer (score 0):

Although you have whitelisted your client IP in Cloud SQL, [GKE has masquerading active](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#how_ipmasq_works) meaning that, all outbound internet connections will be NATed to the node's external address.

> `ip-masq-agent` configures `iptables` rules to handle masquerading node/Pod IP addresses when sending traffic to destinations outside the node’s and cluster's IP ranges. Pod IP addresses are masked behind their node's address.

There are still a [couple of ways to connect to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#before_you_start) from GKE. In my opinion, the most straight-forward is using the [Cloud SQL Proxy deployed as a sidecar container](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine) in your pod.

If the proxy is not an option, you may be able to tweak the [IP masquerade agent](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent) to bypass this SNAT rules and keep the requests' source IPs.